# Constraint on 2 columns in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a table with these rows

```
ID       Code      Prod
-------------------------
1        101       Prod1
2        102       Prod2
3        101       Prod1
4        101       Prod2 -- here I want to prohibit insert
```

So I need for a `Code` to exist only one `Prod`.

With a unique index it's not possible because I have the same 101-Prod1 in multiple rows, but I don't want to have at 101 another Prod

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you are looking for with a `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_ProhibitDupls] ON [dbo].[Products]
   AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS  

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Products
    WHERE Code = (SELECT code FROM inserted) AND Prod <> (SELECT prod FROM inserted)
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('A different product number for this code already exists!',16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

After employing the above `TRIGGER`, if there is already a product with the same code AND a different product number, then `UPDATE` or `INSERT` operation will fail.

Comment: I think that's exactly what the OP *doesn't* want - he wants to allow as many rows with `(101, Prod1)` - but he wants to *prevent* the code (101) being combined with any *other* `ProdX` entry - so he wants any number of `(101, Prod1)` rows - but none like `(101, Prod2)` or `(101, Prod3)` - and that cannot be achieved with a unique constraint....

Comment: @marc_s You are right. I have completely re-written my answer.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thank you ! I was thinking that a constraint can handle this.

Comment: @user3145 You're welcome. You can accept this post as an answer to your question, if it really helped you solve your ploblem, so that other people having a similar problem might benefit from this post.